# How to remain the hidden div shown after submission of the form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am just new here..but the answers here helps me on some of my issues with php and jquery.But right now after searching almost 3 days, I didn't meet my needs.

I have a refine search,an expanded box with input radio labeled websites,apps,domains.In the domains if checked,a div shown on my search selection,like category,price,visitors..etc..,
before category i have a hidden div there that showing when the domain radio is checked.

I can show the div, but if I submit the form(search) the div is disappeared.How can I remain it shown after the form submitted. I want this div hidden when the url is refreshed at the browser.

jquery code is just simple:

```
$("#check_drop").click(function(){
    $("#dom").show();//the id of div when clicked shows
});
```

Tried also

```
$.cookie('mydiv','visible');
```

problem is..when I put var set_div = $.cookie('mydiv','visible');, my radio input wont work anymore or not showing the div.

I hope someone could help me..I will thank you very much..

Comment: does the form submission reload the page? If so, you'd need some JS code, eg. a `$.ready()` to check that cookie and set the div's status

Comment: to quik_silv -> I have tried it but refine search has huge query combinations, I dont know how to do it in Ajax.

Comment: to marck-> I have that complete code here with ready..$(document).ready(function(){
    var menu = $.cookie('mydiv');
    if(menu !== "undefined" && menu == "visible"){
      $("#dom").show();
    }else{
      alert('not set');//try to test if false
    }

    $("#check_drop").click(function(){
      $("#dom").show();
      $.cookie('mydiv','visible');
     }); 
});..problem is..why if I checked back to radio nothing happens..just stuck the radio?